# Please suggest an apple variety that will grow well in Long Island NY without pesticides

Tags: fruit-trees, variety-selection

I am planning on planting 3 to 5 apple trees for eating, baking and cider.  My wife keeps telling me to get some heirloom varieties but I am not sure which ones and where to get them.

I am looking for suggestions from growers for a disease resistant apple tree for my climate.

The tree location is full sun.

Answer (score 2):

You're best choices will include [Liberty,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberty_%28apple%29) [Freedom,](http://dspace.library.cornell.edu/bitstream/1813/5117/1/FLS-103.pdf) and [Enterprise.](https://www.hort.purdue.edu/newcrop/pri/coop30-3.html) These trees are immune to scab, and resistant to fireblight and cedar apple rust. They are often recommended to organic growers because they are very low-spray  and perform well without pesticides, comparably.